# How to avoid showing action "Cut, Copy, Look Up, ..." in swift for IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have UITextFields with doubleTap's gesturecontrol.
UITextFields are created programmaticaly

It doesn't work well because when there's a tap on the UITextField, the menu 'Cut, Copy, ..." opened and the text is selected entirely.

How to avoid this menu to appear ?

edit : 
Didn't work; I added this

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    print(action)
    return false
}
```

I saw in debugger that canPerformAction is called; but I still have the menu!

Comment: You could subclass UITextField, override `canPerformAction` and `return false`.

Comment: I edit my answer, because it don’t work